# How to write a correctly formatted regex for Apache 'DirectoryMatch'?

Tags: regex, apache

I have tried writing this into my config file, to match folders only in that 'example' directory and no further sub-folders...

```
<DirectoryMatch "\/var\/www\/html\/example\/[^/]+\/">
    IndexIgnore ..
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Other regex I have tried...

```
/var/www/html/example/[^/]+/
/var/www/html/example/(.+/){1}
```

If I explicitly write the path to the folder, it works. Where am I going wrong?

I see Apache uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions provided by the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) library.

---

Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` does not need to be escaped. Use `^` and `$` to mark the start and end of the matched path. The trailing slash must be optional (`/?`).

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html/example/?$">
  ...
</DirectoryMatch>
```

or

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html/example/[^/]+/?$">
  ...
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Comment: You're a star! Picking it apart, it seems I just needed the `$` symbol at the end (I am surprised that it is not documented [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directorymatch))

Comment: I only noticed it working though when I changed the `IndexIgnore` to something like `Options -Indexes`. Do you know why `IndexIgnore` does not want to work?

Comment: Why must the trailing slash be optional?

Comment: Says so in [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directorymatch): *This directive applies to requests for directories that may or may not end in a trailing slash, so expressions that are anchored to the end of line ($) must be written with care.*

Comment: Ar okay. Thank you